# React-Native: components only working properly on the last tab loaded in when using react-native-navigation or react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, tabs, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have a very simple two tab app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import {
  Sports,
  News,
} from 'externalComponents';

const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Sports: { screen: Sports },
  News: { screen: News },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

The Sports and News components are provided by another company, and I cannot edit that code. If I load this into a `TabBarIOS` component, everything works fine and all tabs work as intended. However, with `react-native-navigation` and `react-navigation`, only the last tab loaded works properly.

Both the `News` and `Sports` components load a `JSONDownloadService` component like this:

```
downloadService = new JSONDownloadService(this);
```

And then it calls this:

```
downloadService.getJSON(this.state.url, type)
```

Now in `JSONDownloadService` because it has been passed the `NEWS` or `SPORTS` component in its constructor, it gets passed `updateComponent` (the part that is not getting called correctly). The `getJSON()` looks something like this:

```
getJSON(url, type) {
  //set up vars...
    fetch(request, init)
        .then(function (response) {
          // ...some code
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                try {
                 // supposed to call `updateComponent` in News & Sports:
                    callback.updateComponent(response, type);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

The trouble is, `updateComponent()` is only ever called by the last component loaded in the tabBar. If I switch their positions, only the last one ever works. Except, if I comment out the code relating to `JSONDownloadService` in the last tab, THEN the first one works fine. It seems that whichever component last uses it prevents the rest from updating. How can I make this work using `react-native-navigation` or `react-navigation`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the reason `TabBarIOS` worked and `react-navigation` and `react-native-navigation` didn't was because the latter two load all the tabs at once. In this case it overloaded the `JSONDownloadService` component.

I was able to fix it in `react-navigation` at least using this code:

```
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Sports: { screen: Sports },
  News: { screen: News },
}, {
  lazy: true, //used to be called "lazyLoad"
});
```

it just causes the app to lazily load the content for each tab.

Comment: is this still working ? in my code nor lazy or lazyload make any effect with last version of react native ( all the controller are loaded on app start )